# Why does `chrome://flags` return google.com?

Tags: chrome-for-android

Why does `chrome://flags` return `google.com`?

[image]

Answer (score 24):

`chrome://flags` should still work on all versions of Chrome (confirmed on v114).

You probably tapped the search suggestion instead.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I also had tried copy paste to start with, perhaps copied a space.

Comment: Chrome on desktop and android both ignore leading/trailing spaces. So you either selected the wrong suggestion, started with a ?, or were pasting into a search bar (typically found as a home screen widget).